# MySql: xDevApi "collection.modify" not doing anything

Tags: mysql, node.js, document, mysql-x-devapi

I'm testing MySql 8 "XDevApi" with Nodejs, and I'm trying to modify a field in a document

Here is the code :

```js
let vModifyOp=await vCollection.modify('_id = "000062817c620000000000000001"').set('wName','toto');
```

- I don't have any errors or exceptions
- vCollection is a "MySql xDev collection" , "vCollection.getOne" is working fine
- Of course, the document exist

What Am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution by myself. We have to call vModifyOp.execute, so the code will be :

```
let vModifyOp=await vCollection.modify('_id = "000062817c620000000000000001"').set('wName','toto');
vModifyOp.execute();
```

But the "execute" is not specified in the official documentation concerning the "collection.modify"